# What can be done with Lerna that can not be done using Yarn workspaces

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

Trying to figure out the best solution for maintaining a monorepo (MR) of packages.

I see that many blog posts recommend using MR tools such as Lerna/Nx together with Yarn workspaces, as Lerna is used as a "high level wrapper" to "lower level" yarn.

So I've been asking Google this question for few days now, still not sure that I understand, trying my luck here:

"What can be done with Lerna (or nx/turbo/other MR tool), that can not be done using yarn workspaces?"
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Caching. `NX`, `turborepo` – both of them provide remote caching that allows to not execute scripts for files/packages that haven't been changed.

Turborepo docs:

> Turborepo can cache the results and logs of any task in your
> codebase—meaning you never need to do the same work twice.

NX docs:

> Nx has the most sophisticated and battle-tested computation caching
> system. It knows when the task you are about to run has been executed
> before, so it can use the cache to restore the results of running that
> task.

Besides of that, `NX` provides you an ability to see what has been changed since `main` branch for example.

There are some disadvantages between `NX` and `turbo`. You can see them by walking through their documentation.